# Prove that for every $n$ it is possible to find $n$ consecutive positive numbers that are not prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My teacher only wrote this on the board.

\begin{align*}
k \mid (n + 1)!
&\implies k \mid (n + 1)! + k \\
&\implies (n + 1)! + k\text{ is not prime}
\end{align*}

Not exactly sure what he means by this and how it relates to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

$$(n+1)!+2,(n+1)!+3,\ldots (n+1)!+(n+1)$$ are all composite. This is because

$$ a|b \text{ and }a|c  \implies    a|b+c$$

$ \\ $

For example, for $n > 2,\ 3|(n+1)!\ $ and $\ 3|3 \ $ so $ \ 3|(n+1)!+3$

Comment: $n!+1$ doesn't need to be composite.

Comment: yes typo. will fix right now

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo good catch. Thank you. Been very sedated this week because of post surgical pain medication.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $x_k:=(n+1)!+k$ for $k=2,\ldots,n+1$, we have that $x_2,\ldots,x_{n+1}$ are $n$ consecutive composite integers. Indeed, for each $k=2,\ldots,n+1$, we have that
$$x_k=k\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{k}+1\right).$$